# How to remove deleted nodes from Google search?

Tags: 7

When I search my site on goolge, it shows some nodes that are deleted.

How can I remove these results from Google?

If I'm not wrong, with the `Re-Index` button in the search config form It cleans the index and then, with CRON, it fills the index again.

But is there any way to do that automagically when a node is deleted? It's better if not reindex all the index, and only removes the node deleted.

Comment: If you regularly delete content, then that's potentially a problem from an SEO perspective. The question that hasn't been asked is why these nodes have to be deleted. Without knowing that it's not really possible to answer your original question properly.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong The content is not deleted regularly, but I want to make this stuff less manaually as possible for my clients.

Comment: What I am getting at is that before simply deleting content there should be some thinking about what happens in the wider context. If a deleted page turns up in searches that's an opportunity as much as a problem. Better return a 301 than a 404 in response is the short answer. Longer answer: http://searchengineland.com/best-practices-in-e-commerce-seo-176921

Comment: Some of the answers below will work to notify Google that changes have been made, and that is a good thing - keep in mind however that Google will attempt for months or years to access pages it once found, meaning for any deleted content, you will definitely want to provide a redirect as Alfred mentions, regardless of any other action you take

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another good practice is to use [XML sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module and keep everything updated.You can submit this sitemap to [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) and it will automagically get your updated sitemap.

Re-indexing by Google can take two weeks or more...

Comment: Oh, If I have submited the xml sitemap to Google it will get automatically updated in Google searches, so If I delete a node (and the sitemap is updated with that module) Google will re-index automatically (in two weeks or more)?

Comment: your sitemap.xml will be updated on each cron run (?) not 100% sure, so it will update your site.com/sitemap.xml which you have submitted to google.

Comment: Yes, but Google will notice the sitemap.xml changes automatically, or do I have to do something?

Comment: u dont have to do anything, it will crawl it on its regular interval, for example with the setup i told u, one of my sitemaps was crawled on july 3 (yesterday and its been up there for more than three years) http://gsitecrawler.com/en/faq/info/google-sitemaps-2/

Answer (score 2):

Re-indexing definitely needs to be done. I believe when the next crawling happens it will automatically pick valid nodes only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Auto Indexer](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_indexer) module.

> This module should be used when an up-to-date index is
>   desired/required after any addition or update of indexable node
>   content. Not just after the successful execution of cron.php.
>
> **This module is ideal for projects where, other than search indexing,
>   there is no need to run cron often.** Use this module to ensure your
>   search index is up-to-date while keeping the frequency of cron
>   executions to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do something that would stop the Incoming Traffic to your site. I would use [Global Redirect Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) and redirect(after adding an alias from old url to the new one) the deleted links to relevant links on my site.

> GlobalRedirect is a simple module which…
>
> Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if
>   it is not being used.